# How to Reorder Windows of the Same Application in Windows Using a Script?

Tags: windows

I'm looking for some guidance on a scripting task I'm trying to achieve in Windows. I have multiple windows open from the same application, and I'd like to reorder them in the Windows taskbar without closing or minimizing any of them.

Is there a way to do this programmatically using a script, perhaps with AutoHotkey or any other scripting language? My goal is to change the order of these windows in the taskbar without affecting their status within the application itself.

I've done some research, but it seems like a challenging task. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Best regards

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where to start.